# Unable to activate trace with NEST 1.2.0

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Today I updated my nest package to 1.2.0. Now, when I use

```
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool);
connectionSettings.EnableTrace(true); //no problem when trace not enabled
var cli = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
cli.IndexExists(i => i.Index(indexName)).Exists; //throw when trace enabled
```

Then try to check if an index exists, I get

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at
  Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestState.TransportRequestState`1.Dispose()
    in c:\Users\gmarz\code\elasticsearch-net\src\
       Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestState\TransportRequestState.cs: line 181
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is there some regression in this new version?
2. Do you plan to publish the source of the nuget package to a symbol server so I can avoid to download all the sources?

After looking at the code, the dispose method of the transportRequestState throws because the stopwatch object is not initialized. (TransportRequestState.ce ln184). It will work if I do activate metrics or if someone tests _stopwatch obvject before loging

Comment: It looks like the source exists on [GitHub](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net). Can you show us the code for "check if an index exists"? That would be helpful to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in version 1.2.0, originally reported [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/1009).  It's been fixed in [1.2.1](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/1.2.1) which we released earlier today and is now available via nuget.